# How to authenticate a user through certificate exchange?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, tomcat

I have an web application A where a user has to authenticate through a username/pass method (https://server.local/webappA). A secure connection is established (HTTPS) with the server A.

Then, these guys want some sort of 'trickery' to use this same authenticated user to open a different URL (https://server.local:8080/webappB/?param1=PID) and still be sure the authentication is not broken. In other words, they don't want the user to enter his credentials again for webappB. Also, this new webappB should not be accessible to non authenticated users.

WebappB is running in Tomcat and could be hosted on the same server on a different port #. Our job could be a lot easier if webappA had a well known authentication system such as LDAP but they don't. WebappA is from Company A and WebappB is from company B.

Is there any possibility this can work? I personally don't see how, so I might try with you guys. I am free to install any apache mod or server I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't too tricky, assuming both apps can access similar session data.  But only if you can mess around with the code a bit.  Since you're talking about different companies providing the software that second part might not be possible.

Basically when a session is started with `AppA` the username/password is checked against some source (be it a database, IMAP server, LDAP server, whatever), this isn't actually the important part of the process for.  After that first username/password collection, a session *token* is issued.  `AppA` checks the session *token* upon access and if valid; loads the session (so it doesn't require username/password every time you do something).

For this to work you need `AppB` to *(a)* be able to access that session *token* (easy enough, it's likely stored as a cookie), *(b)* access the session data that lists valid tokens and the user's related (if user isn't included with the token in the cookie) and *(c)* create a session in `AppB` without a username/password start, or validate against the existing session.

**Session token access:**

This should just be a matter of reading the cookies supplied to `AppB`.  As long as `AppA` issues the cookie without a restrictive `path` value (low risk since Company A can't know all the folders that `AppA` could operate under).

**Session data access:**

Typically an application would store session information in some sort of a database table.  The only trick might be learning the username associated with a session (the token might include username, or some sort of ID, or neither).  Session validity as defined by `AppA` should be obeyed by `AppB`

**Create AppB Session:**

Probably the trickiest part, if `AppB` has dependency injection on the authentication module, (including session start, session detect and session terminate) then it's just a matter of getting the application to read the same session token as `AppA`, compare/validate against the session data and translate and extend if required.  *Note* unless both apps are modified you'll also want `AppB` to defer logins and possibly logouts to `AppA`

**Security:**

If `AppA` uses a cookie to store/retrieve session information without a path value notice that any other part of the same website can also see this cookie.  If some of the site is served under `http` - including images, style sheets and javascript - this session cookie will be exposed and obtainable by sniffing software (such as firesheep) or hardware.  Serving static content from a different server (or same server under a different name) helps to mitigate this.